# How can Derived class inherit a static function from Base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

```
struct TimerEvent
{
   event Event;
   timeval TimeOut;
   static void HandleTimer(int Fd, short Event, void *Arg);
};
```

HandleTimer needs to be static since I'm passing it to C library (libevent).

I want to inherit from this class. How can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Just inherit and it should work. Are you having any particular problems with it?

Comment: I agree with the above comment, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I third the above comment. :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can easily inherit from that class:

```
class Derived: public TimerEvent {
    ...
};
```

However, you can't override HandleTimer in your subclass and expect this to work:

```
TimerEvent *e = new Derived();
e->HandleTimer();
```

This is because static methods don't have an entry in the vtable, and can't thus be virtual. You can however use the "void* Arg" to pass a pointer to your instance... something like:

```
struct TimerEvent {
    virtual void handle(int fd, short event) = 0;

    static void HandleTimer(int fd, short event, void *arg) {
        ((TimerEvent *) arg)->handle(fd, event);
    }
};

class Derived: public TimerEvent {
    virtual void handle(int fd, short event) {
        // whatever
    }
};
```

This way, HandleTimer can still be used from C functions, just make sure to always pass the "real" object as the "void* Arg".

Comment: no need use static like this,  i would rather use:  Derived t;  t.handle(...);

Comment: Nice solution. `void *arg` is not needed. `static void HandleTimer(int fd, short event, TimerEvent *arg) { arg->handle(fd, event); }` is enough.

Answer (score 30):

To some extent the traits pattern lets you inherit and redefine static methods.

First start with a base class:

```
struct base {
  static void talk()  { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }
  static void shout() { std::cout << "HELLO !!" << std::endl; }
};
```

Then derive it and redefine some methods:

```
struct derived: public base {
  static void talk()  { std::cout << "goodbye" << std::endl; }
};
```

And now call the methods via a traits class:

```
template < class T >
struct talker_traits {
  static void talk() { T::talk(); }
  static void shout() { T::shout(); }
};

talker_traits<base>::talk()     // prints "hello"
talker_traits<base>::shout()    // prints "HELLO !!"

talker_traits<derived>::talk()  // prints "goodbye"
talker_traits<derived>::shout() // prints "HELLO !!"
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/hnGGmf)

The traits class lets you reuse the static method `base::shout` while "overriding" `base::talk` with `derived::talk`. Still, there are several difference with actual inheritance:

- The function to call is resolved at compile time
- The child method needs not have the same signature as the parent one

It works with static fields and typedefs too, the best example is [std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits).

Comment: When I wrote this answer, calling directly `derived::shout()` would raise a compilation error, hence the `traits`class. I checked again, and in newer compiler versions it works, which seems to make the traits pattern less useful.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bit of a conflict here in your question. When you pass `&TimerEvent::TimerHandler` to a C library, you do exactly that. You could also have passed `&DerivedTimerEvent::TimerHandler`, if you wanted. But you can't pass `&TimerEvent::TimerHandler` and expect the *C library* (!) to figure out you actually meant `&DerivedTimerEvent::TimerHandler`.

Comment: Since its `static`, I'd expect the compiler to resolve that long before flow reaches the C library.