# In C++ are static member functions inherited? If yes why ambiguity error does not arise?

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

I am just starting out with gnu-cpp and would like some help. I have come across the ambigutity error while reading and while self-study I came across this idea that static methods of a class should also be affected by the ambiguous diamond problem, but while running the following code ther is no error. Can anyone please explain why?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base
{
  public:
  static void display(){cout<<"Static";}
};
class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Base {};
class Child : public Derived1, Derived2 {};
int main(void)
{
  Child obj;
  obj.display();
}
```

Thank You for the help and time.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998247/are-static-fields-inherited

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515763/how-can-derived-class-inherit-a-static-function-from-base-class

Comment: Base::display() is a private static method in Base,so it should not be callable in main(). Here's a snippet in Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/g/XpyA2m

The default protection for a class is private. You should probably add a "public:" line before the declaration.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that @JonathanO'Connor. Though I did mean the same. Updating it now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's fine according to the lookup rules. You see, when you write member access (`obj.display();`), the member `display` is looked up not just in the scope of the class and its base classes. Base class *sub-objects* are taken into consideration as well.

If the member being looked up is *not* static, since base class sub-objects are part of the consideration, and you have two sub-objects of the same type, there's an ambiguity in the lookup.

But when they *are* static, there is no ambiguity. And to make it perfectly clear, the C++ standard even has a (non-normative) example when it describes class member lookup (in the section [[class.member.lookup]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.member.lookup#9)):

> [ Note: A static member, a nested type or an enumerator defined in a
>   base class T can unambiguously be found even if an object has more
>   than one base class subobject of type T. Two base class subobjects
>   share the non-static member subobjects of their common virtual base
>   classes.  — end note ] [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct V {
>   int v;
> };
> struct A {
>   int a;
>   static int   s;
>   enum { e };
> };
> struct B : A, virtual V { };
> struct C : A, virtual V { };
> struct D : B, C { };
>
> void f(D* pd) {
>   pd->v++;          // OK: only one v (virtual)
>   pd->s++;          // OK: only one s (static)
>   int i = pd->e;    // OK: only one e (enumerator)
>   pd->a++;          // error, ambiguous: two as in D
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Answer (score 4):

The `Base::display` that you get via `Derived1`, and the `Base::Display` that you get via `Derived2`, are literally the same function. With no object context to consider (since they are static) there is no ambiguity here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It's inherited because **it's a class member**.

There's no ambiguity because all that's called with `obj.display()` is that there's only 1 candidate to be chosen, the ultimate "source" `Base::display()`.

This code, however, generates an error:

```
class SuperBase {
    public:
    static void hello() { cout << "Super Base" << endl; }
};

class Base1 : public SuperBase {
    public:
    static void foo() { cout << "Base 1" << endl; }
};

class Base2 : public SuperBase {
    public:
    static void foo() { cout << "Base 2" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {
};

Derived obj;
obj.foo();  // Error: ambiguous resolution
obj.hello();  // No error here
```